# how to encode image base64 formatted

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, base64, nsdata

I am getting image From JSON url.I tried like this but i did't not get image

```
  NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"all NSMutable2%@",al);
        NSDictionary *dict = [al objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString *title=[dict objectForKey:@"dealimage"];
            NSLog(@"all DIC%@",title);

        NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData
                                                     dataFromBase64String:title]];
            NSLog(@"********************************%@",data1);
        NSData* data = [Base64 decode:title ];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        dig=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
        [self.view addSubview:dig];
        dig.frame = CGRectMake(0, 25 , 150,150);
```

My idea is first NSString data converted to NSData and Then NSData pass to UIImage.But No luck 
So Please give me any idea

Comment: Show the data you're logging. Are you base64 decoding twice there? What are those methods you're calling for base64?

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "NSData+Base64.h"

//Creating the data from your base64String
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String: title]];

//Now data is decoded. You can convert them to UIImage
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

 dig=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
 dig.frame = CGRectMake(0, 25 , 150,150);
 [self.view addSubview:dig];
```

Comment: you were decoded in 2 times , that y u can't get in the image ,

Comment: thanks for Reply observed one thing yes decoded in 2 times but i passed only one NSdata to UIImage

Comment: in after this line u were get the data NSData* data = [Base64 decode:title ];

Comment: i placed as you said but i not getting image so Please give me any idea